# floating div object in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

We are using some short code for the display of images on a google maps V3 page. These are static images (not on the map) but in div's.

```
function CoffiControl(controlDiv) {
    var logo = document.createElement('IMG');
    logo.src = '../images/coffi.png';
    logo.style.height = '350px';
    logo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    logo.setAttribute('class', 'floatlegenda');
    controlDiv.appendChild(logo);
}
var logoControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
var logoControl = CoffiControl(logoControlDiv);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push(logoControlDiv);
```

We have maximal 5 of these images what are 350px height and about 90px width. So the images must be appear next to each other but our output shows us they are under each other. They would be toggled by buttons.

```
.floatlegenda {
    float:right;
}
```

As you can see we have put an css class in the script "floatlegenda" that should float the images right, but we use for every image the above script so i think the images come in seperate div's.

Now my question is how can we arrange this to work that every time a button is toggled the new image appear next to the other?

EDIT

Found solution myself!

Just add other images in the same function with unique child names did the trick.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a snippet?

Comment: From reading this it sounds like this has nothing whatsoever to do with google maps? Try rephrasing your question to be more concise and direct. Ignore irrelevant details and include a snippet or fiddle.

Comment: Thanks found solution by myself, i have editted the question with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check that all of your `floatlegenda` are within the same container and that they are all `float: right`. Also, check the width of that container.

This should work. Also, check your output by inspecting the elements. See if the html you're trying to generate is actually what's being generated.

```css
.container {
  display:block;
  
}

.floatlegenda  {
  width:90px;
  height: 350px;
  float:right:
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="floatlegenda" src="" />
  <img class="floatlegenda" src="" />
  <img class="floatlegenda" src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, did it on another way. Creating dynamically with jquery img attributes when buttons are toggled. But thanks for your answer.